# how to remove particular words from strings?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have an NSString *str, having value @"I like Programming and gaming."
I have to remove "I" "like" & "and" from my string so it should look like as "Programming gaming"

How can I do this, any Idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *newString = @"I like Programming and gaming.";
NSString *newString1 = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"I" withString:@""];
NSString *newString12 = [newString1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"like" withString:@""];
NSString *final = [newString12 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"and" withString:@""];
```

Assigned to wrong string variable edited now it is fine

```
NSLog(@"%@",final);
```

output : Programming gaming

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString * newString = [@"I like Programming and gaming." stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"I" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"like" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"and" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

Answer (score 4):

More efficient and maintainable than doing a bunch of `stringByReplacing...` calls in series:

```
NSSet* badWords = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"I", @"like", @"and", nil];
NSString* str = @"I like Programming and gaming.";
NSString* result = nil;
NSArray* parts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString* part in parts) {
    if (! [badWords containsObject: part]) {
        if (! result) {
            //initialize result
            result = part;
        }
        else {
            //append to the result
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", result, part];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Virtual +1 for the thought that went into the long way of doing it ;)

Comment: @Jordan - It's only the long way until there are a dozen or so words that need to be filtered.  By the time there are 100+ words being filtered this approach will look downright compact by comparison.

Comment: I hear you ;) That's why the v+1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question, but I'd like to show my solution:

```
NSArray* badWords = @[@"the", @"in", @"and", @"&",@"by"];
NSMutableString* mString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];

for (NSString* string in badWords) {
     mString = [[mString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:string withString:@""] mutableCopy];
}

return [NSString stringWithString:mString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a mutable copy of your string (or initialize it as NSMutableString) and then use `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` to replace a given string with @"" (empty string).