# Objective-C: Best way to delete substring from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6

If I want to delete a value from the NSString @"this is my book", what should I use?

The return value I want is @"this is book".

Comment: What do you want for `@"my brother Jeremy is myopic but can still read my book"`?

Comment: Utilized methods from given doc => https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html

Comment: Simplest would be `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`. But this is probably too simple, see myopic Jeremy above.

Comment: These links help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594694/how-to-remove-particular-words-from-strings)  to remove all occurrence of a word and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714323/how-to-remove-a-word-from-a-string) to remove first occurrence of a word

Comment: thanks for replying guys but i want to delete a substring from a string with range value in this function - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text thats why i can't use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = @"this is my book";

myString  = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" my " withString:@" "];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Solved my problem, tks!

Comment: @Heitor Glad to know that.

Answer (score -2):

You can use NSRange

```
    NSString *string = @"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"ipsum"];
// {.location=6, .length=5}

NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange: